# Reverse Engineer Sorting Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, reverse-engineering

I have been given 3 algorithms to reverse engineer and explain how they work, so far I have worked out that I have been given a quick sorting algorithm and a bubble sorting algorithm; however i'm not sure what algorithm this is. I understand how the quick sort and bubble sort work, but I just can't get my head around this algorithm. I'm unsure what the variables are and was hoping someone out there would be able to tell me whats going on here:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> SortB(ArrayList<Integer> a)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> array = CopyArray(a);
    Integer[] zero = new Integer[a.size()];
    Integer[] one = new Integer[a.size()];
    int i,b;
    Integer x,p;
    //Change from 8 to 32 for whole integers - will run 4 times slower
    for(b=0;b<8;++b)
    {
        int zc = 0;
        int oc = 0;
        for(i=0;i<array.size();++i)
        {
            x = array.get(i);
            p = 1 << b;
            if ((x & p) == 0)
            {
                zero[zc++] = array.get(i);
            }
            else
            {
                one[oc++] = array.get(i);
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<oc;++i) array.set(i,one[i]);
        for(i=0;i<zc;++i) array.set(i+oc,zero[i]);
    }
    return(array);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), limited to the least significant eight bits. It does not complete the sort unless you change the loop to go 32 times instead of 8.

Each iteration processes a single bit `b`. It prepares a mask called `p` by shifting `1` left `b` times. This produces a power of two - 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., or 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, ... in binary.

For each bit, the number of elements in the original array with bit `b` set to `1` and to `0` are separated into two buckets called `one` and `zero`. Once the separation is over, the elements are placed back into the original array, and the algorithm proceeds to the next iteration.

This implementation uses two times more storage than the size of the original array, and goes through the array a total of 16 times (64 times in the full version - once for reading and once for writing of data for each bit). The asymptotic complexity of the algorithm is linear.

Comment: The asymptotic complexity of a radix sort is debatable. In fact, the first section of the wikipedia article that you cited is titled "Efficiency" and has a good summary of the debate.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, the "debate" over radix sort centers around an argument that the number of bits we must process should be considered a function of `N` (namely, at least `LogN`) based on an implicit assumption that all keys could be distinct. I am not sure if it's a solid assumption, though, especially if we sort lots of small numbers.

Comment: *"based on an implicit assumption that all keys could be distinct"* is more generally worded as *"based on the assumption that the size of the array after removing duplicate keys is O(N)"*. You are correct that the radix sort is linear for the special case where the number of unique keys in the array is much less than N, i.e. the majority of the array consists of repeated keys.

Comment: @user3386109, the debate is rather academical: if you are sorting integers (or longs) in any real life computer program, the number of bits is *a constant*. In a way, it is a "function" of the *data type*, and not the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bit-by-bit radix sort to me, but it seems to be sorting backwards.

Comment: But why the outer loop is being executed only 8 times.

Comment: It is only sorting the lower 8 bits for speed--as the comment says, doing all 32 bits is 4 times slower.